# Получить любую почту пользователя зашедшего на сайт

Tags: api, email, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить почту (mail, google, yandex), хоть какую-нибудь зашедшего на сайт пользователя? Может есть API какое-то.

Comment: спросить его))

Comment: Если бы это возможно было и элементарно, я думаю спам рассылок было в миллионы раз больше. Это из части конфиденциальной информации, которую пользователь должен предоставить по своему желанию а не по вашему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без авторизации пользователя никак. А так у каждого сервиса есть свое API

Comment: Я видел, что есть API у каждого сервиса, но там необходимо подтверждение пользователя на предоставление данных. Просто думал может есть какой-то способ.

Comment: да есть такие способы, только надо заплатить кому-нить чтобы  он за ним слежку установил или как это делается в киберагенствах. ну и при этом надо быть готовым сесть года на три минимум.

Answer (score 4):

Ориентируйтесь на [правила рассылок, например, mail.ru](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/general):

> Получатели в явной форме выразили свое
> желание в получении информации до
> начала рассылки. Убедитесь,  например,
> одним из следующих способов, что вы
> отправляете письма пользователям,
> которые в однозначной форме выразили
> согласие их получать:
>
> - вручную установив галочку «Подписаться на рассылку...» в форме
>   регистрации или подписки (настоятельно
>   не рекомендуется ставить галочку
>   подписки по умолчанию);
> - отправив по e-mail сообщение с запросом на подписку на специальный
>   адрес;
> - кликнув на ссылку подтверждения подписки в письме.
>
> Перед подпиской, обязательно проверьте
> адрес пользователя. Пользователь явно
> должен подтвердить, что является
> владельцем этого почтового адреса.
> Сделать это можно, например, отправив
> по этому адресу письмо с кодом
> активации и инструкцией как
> подтвердить адрес. Также для
> минимизации риска попадания в спам, вы
> не должны приобретать базы данных
> адресов пользователей у третьих лиц
> или собирать адреса с сторонних
> сайтов. Когда пользователи
> подписываются на вашу рассылку, они
> должны иметь представление, какие
> сообщения им будут поступать, как
> часто и как они будут выглядеть.
> Опишите честно, не обманывайте
> ожидания получателей!

Comment: Ладно, спасибо =)